# BotBuilder and Azure AD B2C

Tags: .net, botframework, azure-ad-b2c

I've set up my bot to work with Azure AD using [this official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AadV2Bot) "Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AadV2Bot"

Now, I would like it use a Azure B2C tenant that I've got configured in my Azure subscription, but I don't have a clue of how to do that.

I've already checked the docs, but I'm really lost. I've checked in my Bot Settings page, under **OAuth Connection Settings** but it doesn't show Azure AD B2C in any of the available options:

[image]

Comment: I would see if you can make it work with either the `Generic OAuth 2` or `OAuth 2 Generic Provider` from the service provider list.

Answer (score 1):

Publish the bot as a .NET application and register it under your B2C tenant.

Comment: What do you mean? Could yo please elaborate the answer a bit? Thank you :)